# Java File retrieving from FTP server

Tags: java, file, ftp, connection

I am trying to retrieve a file from ftp server but I get error as below. Would you please help me

> import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
>
> import java.io.File;
>
> import java.io.FileOutputStream;
>
> import java.io.IOException;
>
> import java.io.InputStream;
>
> import java.io.ObjectInputStream.GetField;
>
> import java.io.OutputStream;
>
> import java.text.DateFormat;
>
> import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
>
> import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
>
> import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
>
> import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
>
> import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;
>
> public class FtpTest_V1 {
>
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>
> ```
>     String server = "192.168.200.8";
>
>     int port = 21;
>
>     String user = "Test_user";
>
>     String pass = "123456**";
>
>     FileOutputStream fos = null; 
>
>    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
>
>    try {
>
>           ftpClient.connect(server, port);
>
>           showServerReply(ftpClient);
>
>           ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
>
>
>           int replyCode = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
>
>           System.out.println(replyCode);
>
>
>           //isPositiveCompletion
>
>           if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(replyCode)) {
>
>               System.out.println(FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(replyCode));
>
>               System.out.println(FTPReply.isNegativeTransient(replyCode));
>
>               System.out.println("Connect failed");
>
>               return;
>
>           }
>
>           boolean success = ftpClient.login(user, pass);
>
>           //System.out.println(success);
>
>           showServerReply(ftpClient);     
>
>           if (!success) {
>
>               System.out.println("Could not login to the server");
>
>               return;
>
>           }
>
>           // Lists files and directories
>
>           FTPFile[] files1 = ftpClient.listFiles("TEST2");
>
>           //printFileDetails(files1);                      
>
>           // uses simpler methods
>
>           String[] files2 = ftpClient.listNames("TEST2");
>
>          printNames(files2);
>
>          String[] files = files2;
>
>          for (String aFile: files) {
>
>          String filename = aFile; 
>
>          fos = new FileOutputStream(filename); 
>
>     // Download file from FTP server
>
>    ftpClient.retrieveFile("C://test//FTP_TEST//GET" + filename, >fos); 
>
>           }              
>
>       }       
>
>         catch (IOException ex) {
>
>           System.out.println("An Error Occured"+ex.getMessage());
>
>           System.out.println("Warning! Something wrong happened");
>
>           ex.printStackTrace();
>
>       } finally {
>
>           // logs out and disconnects from server
>
>           try {
>
>               if (fos != null) { 
>
>                   fos.close(); 
>
>                 }  
>
>               if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
>
>                   ftpClient.logout();
>
>                   ftpClient.disconnect();
>
>               }
>
>           } catch (IOException ex) {
>
>               ex.printStackTrace();
>
>           }
>
>       }
>
>   }
>
>   private static void printNames(String files[]) {
>
>       if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
>
>           int i =0;
>
>           for (String aFile: files) {
>
>                i++;
>
>           }
>
>           System.out.println("Number of files = "+i);
>
>           for (String aFile: files) {
>
>               System.out.println(aFile);
>
>           }
>
>       }
>   }
>
>   private static void showServerReply(FTPClient ftpClient) {
>
>       String[] replies = ftpClient.getReplyStrings();
>
>       if (replies != null && replies.length > 0) {
>
>           for (String aReply : replies) {
>
>               System.out.println("SERVER : " + aReply);
>
>           }
>
>       }
> ```
>
> }
>
> }

Here is my Output :

> SERVER : 220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.43 beta
>
> SERVER : 220 Hello FTP SERVER
>
> 220
>
> SERVER : 230 Logged on
>
> number of files = 2
>
> TEST2/testfile.csv
>
> TEST2/tttt.csv
>
> An Error OccuredTEST2\testfile.csv (The system cannot find the path specified)
>
> Warning! Something wrong happened
>
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: TEST2\testfile.csv (The system cannot find the path 
>   specified)
>
> at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
>
> at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
>
> at FtpTest_V1.main(FtpTest_V1.java:74)

Answer (score 1):

The slash should be backwards like this: "C:\ \test\ \FTP_TEST\ \GET" (without the middle space, I put it that way because the html parser in this page change it to only one slash) 
intead of:

```
ftpClient.retrieveFile("C://test//FTP_TEST//GET" + filename, >fos);
```

Or even better:

```
"C:" + File.separatorChar + "test" + File.separatorChar + "FTP_TEST" + File.separatorChar + "GET"
```

Comment: Sorry but still it gives same error as java.io.FileNotFoundException: TEST2\0000047521LZAT00090001_10Palet_253Koli.csv (The system cannot find the path specified)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at FtpTest_V1.main(FtpTest_V1.java:75)

Comment: The eclipse shows that  fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);  as mistake.

Comment: @zorox you need to pass the full path to FileOutputStream, not only the filename, that way only looks in the source folder

Comment: I have written full path but still same problem. The ftp root as below /TEST2

Comment: under  /TEST2  folder there are two files testfile1.csv  and testfile2.csv

Comment: @zorox but not testfile.csv try adding the number to the file name or remove the number in the file name

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have solved the problem as changing the code. try catch block is as below

> ftpClient.connect(server, port);
>
> ftpClient.login(user, pass);
>
> ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
>
> ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
>
> String[] files = ftpClient.listNames("TEST_FILE");
>
> ```
>           for (String aFile: files) {
>
>           String remoteFile1 = aFile;
>
>           File downloadFile1 = new File("C:/test/FTP_TEST
> ```
>
> /GET/"+remoteFile1.replace("TEST_FILE", ""));
>
> ```
>           OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile1));
>
>           boolean success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);
>
>           outputStream1.close();
>
>           if (success) {
>
>               System.out.println("File #1 has been downloaded successfully.");
>
>           }
>
>           }
> ```